# Android - Replace image from Array Adapter position issue

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to replace image from a grid view in custom adapter. When I click on Edit image view, taking new snap from camera going back to my activity, sending back to adapter and trying to replace at that particular position. But it was not showing at that position which I have clicked. Can any one suggest why that position might changing every time after calling `this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Here is my adapter code:

```
public class VehicleImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

    private Context context;
    private List<GridItem> gridItems = new ArrayList();
    int layoutResourceId;

    String[] imageNames = {"Front Right", "Right Doors", "Right Top", "Rear Right",
            "Engine", "Interior FR", "Interior RR", "Trunk",
            "Front", "Interior FL", "Interior RL4", "Rear",
            "Front left", "Left Doors", "Left Top", "Rear Left"};

    private GridItem gridItem;
    private int position;

    public VehicleImageAdapter(Context context, int grid_item_layout, ArrayList<GridItem> gridItems) {
        super(context, grid_item_layout);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = grid_item_layout;
        this.gridItems = gridItems;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        this.position = position;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.vehicleImageNameTV = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.vehicleImageNameTV);
            holder.vehicle_image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.vehicle_image);
            holder.editVehicleImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.editVehicleImage);
            holder.grey = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grey);
            holder.red = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.red);
            holder.green = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.green);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        if (position >= 16) {
            holder.vehicleImageNameTV.setText(imageNames[15]);
        } else {
            holder.vehicleImageNameTV.setText(imageNames[position]);
        }

        Bitmap defaultImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.tap_to_snap);
        holder.vehicle_image.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

        if (gridItems.size() > 0 && !gridItems.isEmpty()) {

            gridItem = gridItems.get(position);

            if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("server")) { //only in server not in local
                Picasso.with(context).load(gridItem.getServerImagePath()).resize(200, 150).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_image).error(R.drawable.ic_error_image).into(holder.vehicle_image);
                holder.grey.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.green.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.red.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("local")) { //only in local not in server
                Picasso.with(context).load(new File(gridItem.getLocalImagePath())).resize(200, 150).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_image).error(R.drawable.ic_error_image).into(holder.vehicle_image);
                holder.grey.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.green.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.red.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("localNewServerOld")) { //local new and server old
                Picasso.with(context).load(new File(gridItem.getLocalImagePath())).resize(200, 150).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_image).error(R.drawable.ic_error_image).into(holder.vehicle_image);
                holder.grey.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.green.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.red.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("localAndServer")) { //local and server
                Picasso.with(context).load(new File(gridItem.getLocalImagePath())).resize(200, 150).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading_image).error(R.drawable.ic_error_image).into(holder.vehicle_image);
                holder.grey.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.green.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.red.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else { // not yet taken
                holder.vehicle_image.setImageBitmap(defaultImage);
                holder.grey.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.green.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.red.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        holder.editVehicleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takeSnap(position);
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

    private void takeSnap(int position) {
        Intent intentFront = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(getVehiclePicPath(position, Constants.vehicalID));
        Constants.editedVehicleImageUrl = mImageCaptureUri;
        Constants.editedImagePosition = position;
        intentFront.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
        try {
            intentFront.putExtra("return-data", true);
            ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intentFront, position);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        int _position;

        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
            this._position = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // if there is no image from server or local take new snap from camera
            if (gridItems.get(_position).getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("notTaken")) {
                takeSnap(_position);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("position", _position);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                if (gridItems != null && !gridItems.isEmpty()) {
                    bundle.putSerializable("gridItems", (Serializable) gridItems);
                }
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView vehicleImageNameTV;
        ImageView vehicle_image;
        ImageView editVehicleImage;
        ImageView grey;
        ImageView red;
        ImageView green;
    }

    public void setGridItems(ArrayList<GridItem> gridItems) {
        this.gridItems = gridItems;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setImageInItem(int position, Uri mImageCaptureUri) {
        GridItem gridItem = getItem(position);
        if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("server")) {
            gridItem.setLocalImagePath(mImageCaptureUri.getPath().toString());
            gridItem.setStatus("localNewServerOld");
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("localNewServerOld")) {
            gridItem.setLocalImagePath(mImageCaptureUri.getPath().toString());
            gridItem.setStatus("localNewServerOld");
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("localAndServer")) {
            gridItem.setLocalImagePath(mImageCaptureUri.getPath().toString());
            gridItem.setStatus("localNewServerOld");
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (gridItem.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("local")) {
            gridItem.setLocalImagePath(mImageCaptureUri.getPath().toString());
            gridItem.setStatus("local");
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    public List<GridItem> getGridItems() {
        return gridItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return gridItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public GridItem getItem(int position) {
        return this.gridItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }


}
```

onActivityResult Code:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != this.RESULT_OK) {
            return;
        }
        showAlertDialog(requestCode);
    }

    void showAlertDialog(final int requestCode) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Photo will be replaced permanently. \n Are you sure want to replace");

        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                final int imagePosition = Constants.editedImagePosition;
                mImageCaptureUri = Constants.editedVehicleImageUrl;

                // set image to vehicle image adapter based on position
                 vehicleImageAdapter.setImageInItem(imagePosition,mImageCaptureUri);

            }
        });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Grid View Looks Like:

[image]

Comment: Where is `onActivityResult` ?

Comment: it is in my Activity

Comment: Show `onActivityResult` code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK updated code please check it

Comment: Image is updating in wrong column or update not happening

Comment: not happening some times and updating in wrong column some times. because of position issue it's changing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132251/discussion-between-shylendra-madda-and--k).

Comment: instead of position try with getAdapterPosition(). takeSnap(getAdapterPosition);

Comment: actually there is no problem with getting position while taking snap.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda: See my answer with OR option

Comment: Here main problem is grid item not reflecting instantly after editing it. Tried `vehicleImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and `this.notifyDataSetChanged();` and `notifyDataSetChanged();`and `gridView.invalidate();` in activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved it by simply calling `invalidate()` on gridView and added gridView again to adapter.

i.e., Added these 2 lines in my Activity

```
gridView.invalidate();
gridView.setAdapter(vehicleImageAdapter);
```

After this line:

> vehicleImageAdapter.setImageInItem(imagePosition,mImageCaptureUri);

And added these lines in Array Adapter in `setImageInItem()` method before `this.notifyDataSetChanged();`

> gridItems.remove(position);
>
> gridItems.add(position, gridItem);

Answer (score 1):

Use notifyDataSetChanged() for adapter and invalidateViews for gridview so it will be refresh both the adapter and gridview.

```
void showAlertDialog(final int requestCode) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Photo will be replaced permanently. \n Are you sure want to replace");

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            final int imagePosition = Constants.editedImagePosition;
            mImageCaptureUri = Constants.editedVehicleImageUrl;

            // set image to vehicle image adapter based on position
                            vehicleImageAdapter.setImageInItem(imagePosition,mImageCaptureUri);

   vehicleImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   gridview.invalidateViews();


        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for  `gridview.invalidateViews();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `showAlertDialog` `onClick` method to update data in  data-source without calling any extra methods like `setImageInItem` from Adapter:

**1.**  get Item from ArrayList which is used as data-source using `Constants.editedImagePosition` in `onClick` of `yes` :

```
GridItem gridItem = gridItems.get(Constants.editedImagePosition);
```

**2.** Update new image url in `gridItem` :

```
gridItem.setLocalImagePath(mImageCaptureUri.getPath().toString());
gridItem.setStatus("local");
```

**3.** Put back `gridItem` in ArrayList at same position:

```
gridItems.add(Constants.editedImagePosition,gridItem);
```

**4.** Now call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onClick` of `yes` :

```
vehicleImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**OR**

Just update selected item in data-source in `setImageInItem` to get it work with current code. add following as last lines in `setImageInItem` method:

```
this.gridItems.add(position,gridItem);
this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I tried your solution but same result, and adding extra columns too so I removed that item before adding like `gridItems.remove(imagePosition);`
but still the image not reflecting instantly

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`vehicleImageAdapter.setImageInItem(requestCode,mImageCaptureUri);`

instead of

`vehicleImageAdapter.setImageInItem(imagePosition,mImageCaptureUri);`